# App crashes when saving record to CloudKit

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit to save records inputted by a user, however my app crashes.

Below is my code:

```
func saveRecordToCloud(_ pinpoint:Details!) -> Void {
    // Prepare the record to save
    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Details")
    record.setValue(pinpoint.title, forKey: "title")
    record.setValue(pinpoint.location, forKey: "location")
    record.setValue(pinpoint.date, forKey: "date")

    // Resize the image
    let originalImage = UIImage(data: pinpoint.image as Data)!
    let scalingFactor = (originalImage.size.width > 1024) ? 1024 / originalImage.size.width : 1.0
    let scaledImage = UIImage(data: pinpoint.image as Data, scale: scalingFactor)!

    // Write the image to local file for temporary use
    let imageFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + pinpoint.title
    try? UIImageJPEGRepresentation(scaledImage, 0.8)?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath), options: [.atomic])

    // Create image asset for upload
    let imageFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
    let imageAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: imageFileURL)
    record.setValue(imageAsset, forKey: "image")


    // Get the Public iCloud Database
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    // Save the record to iCloud
    publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void  in
        // Remove temp file
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: imageFilePath)

        } catch {
            print("Failed to save record to the cloud: \(error)")
        }
        } as! (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)
}
```

The error I receive is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

This is on the line `} as! (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)`, which is the second last.

I am using Swift 3.0

Comment: What line is causing the crash?

Comment: @Pierce The line that says `} as! (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)` which is the last line. I will add this to the question.

Comment: I know what it is -> I'll post an answer. Did this happen after converting your project from an older version of Swift to Swift 3?

Comment: @Pierce Ok, thanks. No, I hadn't converted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this exact same problem when I converted my old Swift 2.x  project to Swift 3. They take the CloudKit completion handlers, and instead of converting them to Swift 3 - it leaves it in Swift 2 and then casts it as a CKCompletionHandler for Swift 3. It always causes a crash. Delete the line that says `as! (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)` from the end of your completion handler. Then go back to your actual completion handler and change it to look like this:

```
publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error: Error?) in
    // Remove temp file
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: imageFilePath)

    } catch {
        print("Failed to save record to the cloud: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Basically you just have to change `NSError` to `Error`, and you can get rid of the `-> void` (returns void) line.  It's superfluous. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Pierce.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes - Sure thing ... Best of luck!